# vArray if else macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro the adds different pages to a pdf based on a check box status.  This is what I currently have.

```
Sub ToyotaMO()
'
' ToyotaMO Macro
'

    Sheets("TC").Visible = True
    Sheets("BS").Visible = True
    Sheets("ToyotaMO").Activate
        If Sheets("ACM").OLEObjects("Toyota").Object.Value = True Then
            vArray = Array("ToyotaMO", "TC", "BS")
        Else
            vArray = Array("Proposal", "TC")
        End If
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vArray).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value & " Toyota Material Only ACM Proposal" & Format(Date, " MMDDYY") & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Sheets("ToyotaMO").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("TC").Visible = False
    Sheets("BS").Visible = False
    Sheets("ACM").Select
    Range("B1").Select
End Sub
```

The macro works on all the other forms the only difference is I need to add worksheet "BS" to the PDF if the checkbox is checked.  VBA always stalls at `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vArray).Select`.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, this will loop through your array and do what you expect:

```
Sub ToyotaMO()
'
' ToyotaMO Macro
'

    Sheets("TC").Visible = True
    Sheets("BS").Visible = True
    Sheets("ToyotaMO").Activate
        If Sheets("ACM").OLEObjects("Toyota").Object.Value = True Then
            vArray = Array("ToyotaMO", "TC", "BS")
        Else
            vArray = Array("Proposal", "TC")
        End If

    For i = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vArray(i)).Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value & " Toyota Material Only ACM Proposal" & Format(Date, " MMDDYY") & ".pdf" _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        Sheets("ToyotaMO").Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        Sheets("TC").Visible = False
        Sheets("BS").Visible = False
        Sheets("ACM").Select
        Range("B1").Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Still stops at the same spot    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vArray(i)).Select